# Questions about punctuation in a light novel

Tags: syntax, punctuation, emphasis

I have the first time of No game No life in Japanese. However, there are some things that puzzled me quite a bit about the punctuation. As you can see in the photo, I don't understand the reason why some words are in square brackets (which I have circled in yellow). Also, I don't really see the usefulness of the black dots that are to the right of kanji and kana (indicated by a red arrow).[image: No game No life, page 11, prologue]

Comment: The question about the "black dots" is answered in this question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15270/1628

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both methods are for emphasizing something, but they are used a little differently.

Brackets are used to emphasize important keywords and words with non-standard meanings. Their role partly overlaps [scare quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes) in English, but Japanese people tend to use them extensively just for highlighting words ([example 1](https://twitter.com/ozantinnippon/status/554800778188042240), [example 2](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29341/5010)). In light novels, you'll notice magic spells and skill names are commonly enclosed in them, too. Various types of brackets are used according to the writer's preference (eg `「」`, `『』`, `【】`, `《》`), and there is usually no significant difference. They're used really often, so you'll get used to them soon. In this case, the words 願望/噂 *may or may not* have some special meaning in the story. You'll see as you read on and understand his writing style.

On the other hand, those dots are technically called [[圏点]{けんてん}](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15270/5010), and they mark something important in the story. Their role is pretty much the same as italics or bolding (or sometimes all-caps) in English. Sometimes it works as a foreshadowing, so you may want to read and think twice. Less commonly, they are also used to highlight an uncommon kana word (e.g. dialect) to reduce misreading.